# Prove $\sigma_{n-1}\ge2n-n^2+(n-1)\sigma_1$ for $(x_1\dots,x_n)\in[0,1]^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $x_1$, $x_2\dots$, $x_n\in[0,1]$, prove that
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{i\ne k}x_i\ge2n-n^2+(n-1)\sum_{k=1}^nx_k.\tag1$$

There is an obvious proof using linearity in each variable, by which we may assume
$$(x_1,x_2\dots,x_n)\in\{0,1\}^n,$$
and it is very easy.

But I want a better inequality proof. I tried to let $x_i=\frac1{y_i}$, then
$$(1)\iff\frac{y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_n}{y_1y_2\cdots y_n}\ge2n-n^2+(n-1)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{y_k}.$$
Perhaps EV theorem helps, but there is a strange constraint $y_i\in[1,+\infty)$.

By the way, there are two equality conditions:
$$(x_1,x_2\dots,x_n)=(1,1,1\dots,1)\text{ or }(0,1,1\dots,1).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y_j=1-x_j$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$. Then $1\leq y_j\leq 0$ and hence, by Weierstrass inequality, we have,

$$\prod_{i\neq j}(1-y_j)\geq1-\sum_{i\neq j}y_j\\\iff \prod_{i\neq j}x_j\geq 1-\sum_{i\neq j}(1-x_j).$$ Summing all inequalities, we get,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{i\neq j}x_j\geq n-n(n-1)+(n-1)\sum_{j=1}^nx_j=2n-n^2+(n-1)\sum_{j=1}^nx_j.$$

Comment: How did you think of substituting $1-x_i$??? It seems very unnatural.